# Convert varchar/char to enum

Tags: mysql, enums, char, varchar

Is there a fast easy way to convert a varchar/char to an enum? I tried to do this but it doesn't work

```
alter table zipcodes add column state_short_enum enum(
    (select state_short from zipcodes group by state_short)
)
```

I get this error:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds
to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 
'(select state_short from zipcodes group by state_short))' at line 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An enumeration value must be a literal thus you can't use user variables or scalar subquery. Probably you will have to create `ALTER` statement as a string.

Example:

```
SET @codes := CONCAT((SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT("'", state_short, "'")) FROM zipcodes), "'");
SET @alter_sql := CONCAT('ALTER TABLE `zipcodes` ADD `state_short_enum` ENUM(', @codes, ')');
PREPARE stmt FROM @alter_sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
```

Answer (score 0):

I know, it's already obsolete question, but I found it while trying to solve similar problem. In MySQL upto version 8.0 there is a'[procedure analyse](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/procedure-analyse.html)', which is easy to use:

```
select * from t procedure analyse()\G
```

and it gives you optimal field type in 'Optimal_fieldtype' column. You may use this result directly in alter:

```
alter table t change column col1 enum(...) not null;
```

Of course all precautions should be made before doing alter (make backup, ensure that lock held on the table during alter will not disrupt normal activity).